# Extend width to screen width

Tags: width, navbar, fixed-width

I want to increase following things :

1. the border line below my top social link width
2. the navigation bar width
3. the footer social link width
   across the width of the screen (to fit screen)

Can't seems to find the correct coding area to adjust.

My page: http://adelinesays.blogspot.com

Comment: Share some code, show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The .outerwrapper class has an 1100px width on it. You can remove that and it will make the social border and footer expand to fit the screen. Then you can target the nav div with something like width: 100%.

Comment: Thanks! That works. the width of the nav div is actually already 100% but still not adapted across the screen.